# Linker error due to "__cdecl" and "__thiscall" Calling convention mismatch when using MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, calling-convention

I am using Visual Studio 2008.  I am getting the a linker error when building a project that contains a statically linked library only when using MFC CString (vs std::wstring).

So this works:

```
//header
class FileProcessor
{
    public:
        class iterator;
        friend class iterator;
    //...

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>>
    {
    public:
    //...
    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> operator*() const; 
    }
} 


//cpp 
std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> FileProcessor::iterator::operator*() const
{
    return _outerRef->_pimpl->_saxHandler->GetCurrentTable();
}
```

But this

```
//header
#include <afx.h>

class FileProcessor
{
    public:
    class iterator;
    friend class iterator;
    //...

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::vector<std::vector<CString>>>
    {
    public:
        //...
        std::vector<std::vector<CString>> operator*() const; 
    }
} 


//cpp 
std::vector<std::vector<CString>> FileProcessor::iterator::operator*() const
{
    return _outerRef->_pimpl->_saxHandler->GetCurrentTable();
}
```

gives the linker error:

```
FileProcessingTests.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class
std::vector<class std::vector<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct 
std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class std::allocator<class 
std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class 
std::allocator<wchar_t> > > >,class std::allocator<class std::vector<class 
std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class 
std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct 
std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > > > __thiscall 
FileProcessing::FileProcessor::iterator::operator*(void)const "
(??Diterator@FileProcessor@FileProcessing@@QBE?AV?$vector@V?$vector@V?$basic_string@_WU?
$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits
@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@V?$basic_string@_WU?$
char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits
@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void 
__cdecl TestUnicodeSingleTable(void)" (?TestUnicodeSingleTable@@YAXXZ)
```

In both projects, the calling convention is specified as `__cdecl` in the project file. So why is `__thiscall` even arising, and how can I fix it?  I have to use `__cdecl` because I am referencing external libraries that use `__cdecl`.

**Additional project settings:**

Both projects have these configuration settings:

- "Use Of MFC" : Use MFC in a Shared DLL
- "Use Of ATL" : Not Using ATL
- "Character Set": Use Unicode Character Set

Comment: Please edit your question (I was in the process of doing so when you edited it twice and I had to discard my changes) to add some line breaks in the error message to remove the ridiculous horizontal scrolling. It's fine to improve the formatting so your question is readable, you know. (Including perhaps some line breaks in your class declarations so they don't cause horizontal scrolling either.)

Comment: @Ken White - done.  Sorry for stepping on your edits.

Comment: No problem. Just figured it was better to get you to go ahead and do it instead of wrestling you for it. :-)

Comment: __thiscall is used by C++ classes' member functions, its not in the same context of __cdecl and __stdcall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `FileProcessingTests.cpp` isn't being rebuilt or it's using a stale header.  That object file is still trying to link to the `std::wstring` variant rather than the `CString` variant.

The error message is a verbose way of saying that the unresolved external symbol is for:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> FileProcessor::iterator::operator*() const
```

Keep in mind that `std::wstring` is just a typedef for:

```
class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >
```

if you make the default template parameters explicit. The error message is also making the default template parameters for `std::vector` explicit as well, which is why the error message has such horrendous spew.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The __thiscall calling convention is used on member functions and is
>   the default calling convention used by C++ member functions that do
>   not use variable arguments.

So the __thiscall is the default calling convention for methods. This may be the problem.

I suggest trying adding a __cdecl for the methods you have problems with to see what happens.